# How to fix an issue with an abstract class error

Tags: java, class, user-interface, compiler-errors, abstract

When I try to compile the following code, it tells me that it is not an abstract class and does not override abstract method actionPerformed. How do I fix this?

Here is the code I am attempting to compile:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class FinalProj1 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
static FinalProj1 objFrame;
static Button objButton1;
static Button objButton2;
static TextField count = new TextField(20);
static TextField count2 = new TextField(20);
static Label objLabel;
static Label objLabel2;

FinalProj1()
{
    setTitle("Click Counter");
    setSize(400,400);
    show();
}
public static void main(String args[])
{   
    objFrame= new FinalProj1();
    objButton1= new Button("Agree");
    objButton2= new Button("Dissagree");
    objLabel= new Label();
    objLabel2= new Label();
    objLabel2.setText("Mexican Food Is Better Than Chineese Food");

    objButton1.setBounds(110,175,75,75);
    objButton2.setBounds(190,175,75,75);
    objLabel2.setBounds(80,95, 250,25);

    objFrame.add(objButton2);
    objFrame.add(objButton1);
    objFrame.add(objLabel2);
    objFrame.add(objLabel);

    objButton1.addActionListener(objFrame);
    objButton2.addActionListener(objFrame);

    int numClicks = 0;
    int numClicks2 = 0;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
{
     objButton1.addActionListener(this);
     objButton2.addActionListener(this);
     if(e.getSource()==objButton1)
        {
            numClicks++;
        }
        else
        {
            numClicks2++;
        }
        count.setText("There are " + numClicks + " who agree");
        count2.setText("There are " + numClicks2 + " who dissagree");
    }
}
```

Comment: `does not override abstract method actionPerformed`...

Comment: Why did you make your class implement `ActionListener` if you're not going to implement its methods?

Comment: `actionPerformed(ActionEvent);` As it is now you are trying to call this method, then after it you have just a block of code. The 2 aren't linked like you think they are. (I think :)).

Comment: I really don't know. I'm taking a beginning java class online and for the final project it said to write this program to count the clicks on each button even though nothing that advanced was even mentioned in the course. So I've been trying to piece together the code from tutorials and suggestions from people on here.

Comment: Don't do this without knowing what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 actionPerformed(ActionEvent);
{
    objButton1.addActionListener(this);
    objButton2.addActionListener(this);
    if(e.getSource()==objButton1)
    {
        numClicks++;
    }
    else
    {
        numClicks2++;
    }
    count.setText("There are " + numClicks + " who agree");
    count2.setText("There are " + numClicks2 + " who dissagree");
}
```

actionPerformed is a method defined in the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface, and since you're implementing that interface your class has to implement that method.  The problem is that you've put the body of the method `actionPerformed` inside your main method and you haven't declared it as a method.  What you should do is remove the actionPerformed part you currently have and add it as a method after your main method, like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    objButton1.addActionListener(this);
    objButton2.addActionListener(this);
    if(e.getSource()==objButton1)
    {
        numClicks++;
    }
    else
    {
        numClicks2++;
    }
    count.setText("There are " + numClicks + " who agree");
    count2.setText("There are " + numClicks2 + " who dissagree");
}
```

and then as Takendarkk mentioned, you have to add these two lines in your main method:

```
objButton1.addActionListener(objFrame);
objButton2.addActionListener(objFrame);
```

Now there's one last problem.  Since actionPerformed is a different method, it won't be able to access variables in main, so you should move them outside your main method and make them static variables like so: (put this before anywhere in your class, preferably at the top)

```
static FinalProj1 objFrame;
static Button objButton1;
static Button objButton2;
static TextField count = new TextField(20);
static TextField count2 = new TextField(20);
static Label objLabel;
static Label objLabel2;
```

and remove those declarations from the main method.

Comment: This answer is much better. I'm on my phone, had to make it short :)

Comment: @user3233707 Hmm, sounds like there's an extra brace or a brace missing somewhere, tough to tell without seeing the code.  Try looking through it and see if you notice any typos with curly braces, make sure you open the class with a brace, have opening and closing braces for each method, and then a closing brace for the class.

Comment: Yeah I just had an extra brace. But it's now giving me the error "non-static variable objFrame cannot be referenced from a static context"  @IburiNoc

Comment: @user3233707 Oh whoops, I forgot, the declarations of the variables must be static as they don't belong to the specific instance of FinalProj1.  Basically they must be static for the same reason as main must be static.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @IburiNoc Thank You! One last thing (hopefully): I'm now getting the same static context error for the variable "this" in the     objButton1.addActionListener(this); line. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @user3233707 Yeah sorry that was a mistake that both me and Takendarkk made, I changed it a while ago but you may not have noticed.  In the line with the error, it should be `objButton1.addActionListener(objFrame);` instead, as I have in my answer.

Comment: @IburiNoc I really hate to keep bothering you with my undoubtedly simple problems, but I keep getting errors that this online class has given me no tools to deal with. I'll edit my original question to show my current code if you wouldn't mind looking at it again? I'm currently getting the error "actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);" is missing a method body

Comment: @user3233707 No problem, simple issue, you have a semi-colon after `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, which shouldn't be there as it separates the method header from the method body.

Comment: @IburiNoc it works!! Thank You soooo much for all of your help. Just one last question; is there any way to make it add up all of the votes as opposed to having the numbers alternate between 0 and 1? If there's not a simple solution, don't worry about it I'll just turn it in as is. Either way I am eternally indebted to you. Thank you a million times over!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having the numbers alternate between 0 and 1, they shouldn't be... it might be that you need to declare numClicks and numClicks2 as a static variable as well, outside the main method.  @Takendarkk there, you get an upvote for answering quickly :)

Comment: I know it was quick and dirty, but like I said I was on my phone and can't type well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this method.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Your code here will be performed when an action occurs
}
```

You also need to move these 2 lines (along with your other object instantiations) into your constructor.

```
objButton1.addActionListener(this);
objButton2.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: I know it's not a whole solution but it should help. The whole give a man a fish thing...

Comment: 'this' in a static method? really?